# Proper metric for measuring the similarity between two images

Tags: machine-learning, python, computer-vision, similarity, mse

I want to calculate the similarity between these two images:

[image: original]

and

[image: reconstructed]

These are brain topography maps and colors inside the circles represent the area being activated while watching TV. Thus **I am looking for a metric which computes the similarity between original and reconstructed image taking into account how much they are similar with respect to the "activated" areas**.

As you can see the two images are not very similar since, in the original image, the activated (white) area is left-side while in the reconstructed one the activated area is right-side.

For doing that, I am combining both [SSIM](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.metrics.html#skimage.metrics.structural_similarity) (scaled between 0 and 1) and [MSE](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.metrics.html#skimage.metrics.mean_squared_error) using this formula:

```
ssim = scaled_ssim(original_image, reconstructed_image)  # between 0 and 1
mse = mean_squared_error(original_image, reconstructed_image)
score = ssim / (mse + 1)
```

where `scaled_ssim` is defined as follows:

```
def scaled_ssim(original, reconstructed):
    original = normalize(original) 
    reconstructed = normalize(reconstructed)
    score = ssim(original, reconstructed, data_range=1, channel_axis=-1)
    return (score + 1) / 2
```

and `normalize` is defined as follows:

```
def normalize(x):
    return (x - np.min(x)) / (np.max(x) - np.min(x))
```

And I am getting:

```
ssim on random test sample: 0.5712
mse on random test sample: 0.0004
score on random test sample: 0.5710
```

As you can notice, the `score` is `0.5710`, which is not that low as I would have expected.

Can you suggest me a metric which performs better, that is takes into account the activation areas of the circles?